# AWS Go SDK not finding the credentials file at C:/###/.aws/credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, credentials, amazon-kinesis

I am using Amazon Kinesis and the Go SDK for AWS, but I'm getting an error.

This is my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "strings"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    _kinesis "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/kinesis"
)

func main() {
    session, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1"),
    })

    handleErr(err)

    kinesis := _kinesis.New(session)

    laugh := strings.Builder{}
    laughingSounds := []string{"haha", "hoho", "hehe", "hehehe", "*snicker*"}

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        laugh.WriteString(laughingSounds[rand.Intn(len(laughingSounds))])
    }

    _, err = kinesis.PutRecord(&_kinesis.PutRecordInput{
        Data:         []byte(laugh.String()),
        PartitionKey: aws.String("laughs"),
        StreamName:   aws.String("laughs"),
    })

    handleErr(err)
}

func handleErr(err error) {
      if err != nil {
             panic(err)
      }
}
```

When I run this, I get an error:

```
panic: UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid.
        status code: 400, request id: dc139793-cd38-fb30-86a3-f92b6410e1c7

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.handleErr(...)
        C:/Users/####/----/main.go:5
main.main()
        C:/Users/####/----/main.go:34 +0x3ac
exit status 2
```

I have run `aws configure`:

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]:  ####
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: ####
Default region name [None]: us-east-1
Default output format [None]:
```

and the C:/users/####/.aws/credentials file is created with the correct configuration. But my program still wouldn't execute successfully.

I tried to set an environment variable, but to no avail.

```
$ $env:aws_access_key_id="####"
```

Version info:

```
$ pwsh -v
PowerShell 7.2.2
$ aws -v
aws-cli/2.4.27 Python/3.8.8 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off
```

OS: Windows 11

Comment: "The security token included in the request is invalid." this implies that either you're specifying a long term credential and also a security token, or that you're specifying a short term credential without a security token.  Where did you get your credentials, possibly SSO or STS Assume Role?

Comment: I went [to this page](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#/security_credentials) and I clicked on the Access Keys section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in GoDoc, I just had to change a config setting and use `NewSessionWithOptions`:

```golang
session, err := session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
    Config: aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("<your region>"),
    }, SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
})
```

Be sure to run `aws configure` with the correct credentials (or even just manually create the `~/.aws/credentials` file), or this won't work.